# PostgreSQL русский словарь для полнотекстового поиска

Tags: кодировка, postgresql, utf-8, словари, полнотекстовый-поиск

Я пытаюсь добавить русский словарь для полнотекстового поиска в PostgreSQL.
Преобразовал в UTF-8:

```
iconv -f koi8-r -t utf-8 < ru_RU.aff > /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/share/postgresql/tsearch_data/russian.affix 
iconv -f koi8-r -t utf-8 < ru_RU.dic > /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/share/postgresql/tsearch_data/russian.dict
```

и попытался создать новый словарь:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY russian_ispell (
 TEMPLATE = ispell,
 DictFile = russian,
 AffFile = russian,
 StopWords = russian
);
```

Но получил сообщение об ошибке:

```
ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xd1
CONTEXT: line 341 of configuration file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.1/share/postgresql/tsearch_data/russian.affix": "SFX Y хаться шутся хаться"
```

Как я можно исправить эту ошибку?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте https://code.google.com/p/hunspell-ru/ - этот словарь полнее и не требует конвертации в utf-8. Postgres также поддерживает этот формат.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?